# Установка XAMPP после удаления Denwer

Tags: xampp, denwer

Вот скажите, у меня после непонятных событий (просто лег спать, а на утро  **1045 access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'**), я решил уничтожить denwer и поставить XAMPP, но после удаления денвера и установки Хампа, у меня при запуске localhost

> `К сожалению, Google Chrome не может открыть страницу localhost.
> Возможно, вы имели в виду: localhost.­net.­ua
> Возможные действия:
> Перейдите на страницу localhost.­com
> Перейдите на страницу localho.­st
> Снова откройте страницу: localhost
> Искать в Google:`

И так во всех браузерах. Что делать?

Comment: Да есть....

Comment: А вы уверены, что XAMPP запущен и ничего ему не мешает?

Comment: Насчет того что ему ничего не мешает, я не уверен(т.к не знаю где проверить), а то что запущен точно.

Comment: Если мешает, то он точно не запущен. Проверяйте консолью:

> telnet 127.0.0.1 80

Comment: Проверил, даже прочитать не успел. Просто открылось появилось 3 строки, прочитать не успел, и сразу закрылось.

Comment: А вы откройте консоль сперва (Выполнить - "cmd"), а затем пробуйте команду

Comment: Не удалось открыть подключение в этому узлу, на порт 80. Сбой подключения

Comment: Правильно, и это значит, что Апач у вас не запущен. Ищите проблему. Загляните в лог он валяется в директории `xampp/apache/logs/errors` можете его сюда прикрепить, если не очень большой, если большой, то удалите и перезапустите сервер.

Answer (score 1):

А вы уверены, что XAMPP запущен и ничего ему не мешает (например скайп)?

В консоли (Выполнить - "cmd") попробуйте `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`

Ошибка:

> Не удалось открыть подключение в этому узлу, на порт 80. Сбой подключения

говорит о том, что Апач у вас не запущен. Ищите проблему. Загляните в лог он валяется в директории `xampp/apache/logs/errors` можете его сюда прикрепить, если не очень большой, если большой, то удалите и перезапустите сервер.

Answer (score 0):

> 1045 access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Это ругается mysql

Может, вы пароль сменили?

При установке xampp вы порт другой, случаем, не выбирали? Или, может, xamp сам выбрал другой порт, так как на момент установке 80й порт был занят.

Попробуйте удалить и денвер и xampp, перезагрузить компьютер и заново поставить xamp, **при этом быть внимательным при установке и смотреть (*и читать!*), что там пишется**.

Answer (score 0):

Установите денвер заново - это всего лишь изменение пароля, это легко исправляется